# Eclipse CDT - Unresolved Inclusion for VLFeat

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I am trying to run the HelloWorld program from VLFeat in Eclipse CDT in Ubuntu. The code is

```
extern "C" {
#include <vl/generic.h>
}     

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
VL_PRINT ("Hello world!") ;
return 0;
}
```

This shows Unresolved Inclusion error for the line #include . I can see the generic.h file in "/home/username/vlfeat-0.9.19/vl" folder. However, eclipse is not able to include this.

I have the following options in my project properties which must be related to this.

1. Project >Properties >C/C++ Build > GCC Compiler > Includes > Include Paths(-l) & Include files (-include)
2. Project >Properties >C/C++ Build > GCC Linker > Libraries > Libraries (-l) & Library Search Paths (-L)

What does each of these options mean? What is the purpose of these? And how should I fix my present issue?

I can run a normal cpp hello world program successfully without adding anything in the include paths or directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem that you have!

Follow [these](https://nibblesandbytes.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/setting-up-vlfeat-with-the-eclipse-ide-on-ubuntu/) instructions and your problem will probably be fixed.

Some notes:

- Replace "VLFEATROOT" with the path to your vlfeat
  folder.
- Replace "glnx86" with your system info ( "glnx86" for linux 32bit, "glnx64" for 64bit linux, win32 for windows 32 bit)

Any doubt in the process just ask :)

For the first questions I will search for an anwser and I will edit this post soon with them. Good luck!